# Uploading to Amazon S3 from Zip File Using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am trying to upload an image using paperclip. But the images are stored in zip folder.

```
imagepath = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/game_contents/pictures.zip"
        zip = Zip::ZipFile.open(imagepath) 
        image = zip.find_entry fileName
        gameContent.task_photo = image
        gameContent.save
```

I got this error:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError: No handler found for #<Zip::ZipEntry
```

Probably the image = zip.find_entry fileName is not an image. maybe it's only a string? 
If yes, what is the right way to do that?
thanks

Comment: What is the gem and its version you use for the unzip?